# +1 from Versatile Weapons

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons

Should be an easy question: if you use a versatile weapon with two hands, it adds +1 to damage. Does it work like Brutal, where it is dependent on the number of dice, or is it a straight +1?

In other words, if I use a versatile weapon two-handed and do 2[W], is it +1 or +2 for weapon damage?

Comment: Brutal and related effects are very unusual; they aren't good models for understanding the rest of 4e.

Comment: Is Brutal even intended to work that way, or is it more of a "how else can we describe this" sort of side-affect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A versatile weapon grants an untyped +1 bonus to damage when used two-handed.  It's not +1 per die.

Comment: Good point. I always thought it should be a +1 per die but effectively it is not so. In my opinion this rule was designed to be an approximation (a simpler and quicker way than increasing the weapon damage die) so that, for example, a 1d8 longsword [1-8] wielded with both hands [2-9] is - on average - more similar to a 1d10 weapon [1-10].

Answer (score 4):

I believe like a feat bonus, magic weapon bonus or any other type of bonus it is applied only once. The [W] only refers to the specific die of that weapon, not to any modifiers that apply.

Modifiers are always applied once, brutal applies to each die of damage.